# Rspec failing while upgrading RubyGem-rails to 4.2.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, rubygems

I am upgrading `rails` from 4.1 to 4.2.x. I am facing multiple issues while upgrading it. As of now `rspec` is failing with following error :

> Warning: you should require 'minitest/autorun' instead.
>
> Warning: or add 'gem "minitest"' before 'require "minitest/autorun"'

I have also added `minitest` in my Gemfile.

Can you please help me in figuring out on how this can be removed?

**Update:**

My `rspec_helper.rb` has `require 'rspec/autorun'`. I replaced it with `require 'minitest/autorun'`. I still run into same error.

Comment: Did you try to do what the warning message tells you to do?

Comment: I added gem 'minitest' in my GemFile

Comment: My rspec_helper.rb contains "require 'rspec/autorun' " Do I need to change that also?

Comment: That's just a warning - you don't need minitest explicitly  in your Gemfile. Is something in your app requiring a file from minitest?

Comment: No.Things were working fine when I was running my app in Rails 4.1 this is happening while upgrading to Rails 4.2

Answer (score 0):

`require "rspec/autorun"` was deprecated in RSpec 3, so is not the solution to your problem. You should remove it. You should also remove `minitest` from your `Gemfile`. It's likely being pulled in by a dependency, having you explicitly specify it won't change anything.

`minitest` and `rspec` are two separate libraries. The warning is not coming from `rspec`. I'm guessing you're just seeing it when you run your test suite. My best guess is that one of your test libraries is loading minitest some how. It's a big hammer, but you can try installing all your gems to a local cache `bundle install --vendor` and then grepping for minitest: `grep minitest/autorun -R .` to try and locate.